# Grails 3.3.9 and Grails Spring Security Core Plugin login/auth Not Found

Tags: spring-security, grails-3.3

For a project I would like to use Grails 3.3.9 and springsecurity.
Unfortunately I get a not found after starting the application for localhost:8080/login/auth. I've used the combination Grails and spring security a dozen times and it always worked.

I did the following:

1. I've created a new grails project in Intellij with Grails 3.3.9 SDK and Java 8 JDK
2. Then I started the project and everything went as expected.
3. After that I added the dependency compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3' to build.gradle. The download of all components was successful
4. After that I used grails s2-quickstart com.testapp User Role Requestmap to create the domain classes.

The domain classes were generated as expected. In /views and /controllers nothing was created. As far as I understood the documentation, the standard controllers and views of the plugin are used.

When I start the application, I'm always redirected to http://localhost:8080/login/auth and I get a "Not found" in my browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

The rejectIfNoRule setting (SpringSecurity) is set to true by default, so you have to create some request maps (at least one for your LoginController) to access the login.

```
def loginRequestMap = new Requestmap(configAttribute: 'permitAll', url: '/login/auth', httpMethod: 'GET').save()
```

Alternatively, you can set rejectIfNoRule and rejectPublicInvocations setting to false, inside your application.groovy (I cannot recommend this):

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false`